# How can I app launcher with argument "--without-update" in Mac OS, Please?

Tags: applescript

Don't work:
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Rambox.app --without-update
Result:
error "Can’t make missing value into type real."

$ /Applications/Rambox.app --without-update
Result:
error "Can’t make missing value into type real."

do shell script "exec /Applications/Rambox.app --without-update"
error "sh: /Applications/Rambox.app: is a directory
sh: line 0: exec: /Applications/Rambox.app: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0"

do shell script "/Applications/Rambox.app --without-update"
Result:
error "sh: /Applications/Rambox.app: is a directory"

do shell script "open /Applications/Rambox.app --without-update"
Result:
error "open: unrecognized option `--without-update'
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b ] [-a ] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.
If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options:
-a Opens with the specified application.
-b Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
-e Opens with TextEdit.
-t Opens with default text editor.
-f Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
-F --fresh Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
-R, --reveal Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
-W, --wait-apps Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
--args All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
-n, --new Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
-j, --hide Launches the app hidden.
-g, --background Does not bring the application to the foreground.
-h, --header Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them." number 1

do shell script "open -a /Applications/Rambox.app --without-update"
Result:
error "open: unrecognized option `--without-update'
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b ] [-a ] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.
If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options:
-a Opens with the specified application.
-b Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
-e Opens with TextEdit.
-t Opens with default text editor.
-f Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
-F --fresh Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
-R, --reveal Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
-W, --wait-apps Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
--args All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
-n, --new Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
-j, --hide Launches the app hidden.
-g, --background Does not bring the application to the foreground.
-h, --header Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them." number 1
do shell script "open -a '/Applications/Rambox.app'--without-update"

open /Applications/Rambox.app --without-update
A unknown token can’t go after this identifier.

open /Applications/Rambox.app
A unknown token can’t go after this identifier.

#!/bin/sh
open /Applications/Rambox.app
result: error "FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Rambox.app--without-update) failed with error -43."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the *command line* version of `open` *command*, then the first thing you need to do is read the *manual page* for the `open` *command*. In **Terminal**: `man open`

There you will learn that any *arguments* you want to pass to the *application* being opened is to use the `--args` *option* of the `open` *command*, e.g.:

```
open -a Rambox --args --without-update
```

To use this in a `do shell script` *command* in **AppleScript**, e.g.:

```
do shell script "open -a Rambox --args --without-update"
```

**Notes:**

I'm using the *short form* of the *name* of the *application*, however, if it has an issue with it, then use the *long form*, e.g:

```
do shell script "open -a /Applications/Rambox.app --args --without-update"
```